# new line within createTextNode

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to create a new paragraph in a div:

And I want to use new lines in the paragraph. I am escaping them using \n but they are creating new lines. What am I doing wrong?

```
var oNewP = document.createElement("p");
var oText = document.createTextNode("Harry Huy\nPresident\n283.423.6431\nharry.huy@hello.com");
oNewP.appendChild(oText);
document.body.appendChild(oNewP);

var Test = document.getElementById('Test');
Test.appendChild(oNewP);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4qvydycf/4/

Comment: Not possible, `\n` is not recognized by HTML. You've to create a `br` element.

Comment: I've seen that solution. Why is it that "\n" acts as a space in the output, though?

Comment: Although it's not recognized as a line-break, it is a character, which takes its space. Quentin has a good explanation below.

Answer (score 4):

A new line in a text does doesn't usually create a new line in an HTML document. It doesn't matter that you are using JavaScript. The result is the same as having…

```
<p>Harry Hun
President
```

… in the HTML. The new line is treated like any other whitespace (new line, tab, space) character.

You deal with this in the same way that you do in HTML. Either:

- Use multiple text nodes with `br` elements between then
- Use the CSS `white-space` property
- Use an element that applies the `white-space` property by default (like `pre`).

Answer (score 3):

The `\n` is not an HTML element, use `<br />` element instead. However the `createTextNode` is not render the text as HTML, so you need to do something like this:

```
var Test = document.getElementById('Test');
Test.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Harry Huy"));
Test.appendChild(document.createNode('br'));
Test.appendChild(document.createTextNode("President"));
Test.appendChild(document.createNode('br'));
Test.appendChild(document.createTextNode("283.423.6431"));
Test.appendChild(document.createNode('br'));
Test.appendChild(document.createTextNode("harry.huy@hello.com"));
```

Comment: `document.createNode` does not exist. Use `document.createElement` instead.

Answer (score 0):

just use the tag pre and leave the paragraph as you concatenate it with \n  like this:

```
    var oNewP = document.createElement("pre");
    var oText = document.createTextNode("Harry 
Huy\nPresident\n283.423.6431\nharry.huy@hello.com");
    oNewP.appendChild(oText);
    document.body.appendChild(oNewP);

    var Test = document.getElementById('Test');
    Test.appendChild(oNewP);
```